# Handling Xarray/Dask Memory

Tags: dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I'm trying to use Xarray and Dask to open a multi-file dataset. However, I'm running into memory errors.

I have files that are typically this shape:

```
 xr.open_dataset("/work/ba0989/a270077/coupled_ice_paper/model_data/coupled/LIG_coupled/outdata/fesom//LIG_coupled_fesom_thetao_19680101.nc")                          

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (depth: 46, nodes_2d: 126859, time: 366)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1968-01-02 1968-01-03 ... 1969-01-01
  * depth    (depth) float64 -0.0 10.0 20.0 30.0 ... 5.4e+03 5.65e+03 5.9e+03
Dimensions without coordinates: nodes_2d
Data variables:
    thetao   (time, depth, nodes_3d) float32 ...
Attributes:
    output_schedule:  unit: d first: 1 rate: 1


30 files --> 41.5 GB
```

I also can set up a `dask.distributed Client` object:

```
Client()
<Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:43229' processes=8 threads=48, memory=68.72 GB>
```

So, if I suppose there is enough memory for the data to be loaded. However, when I then run `xr.open_mfdataset`, I very often get these sorts of warnings:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 8.25 GB -- Worker memory limit: 8.59 GB
```

I guess there is something I can do with the chunks argument?

Any help would be very appreciated; unfortunately I'm not sure where to begin trying. I could, in principle, open just the first file (they will always have the same shape) to figure out how to ideally rechunk the files.

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Examples of the `chunks` and `parallel` keywords to the opening functions, which correspond to how you utilise dask, can be found in [this doc section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#reading-and-writing-data).

That should be all you need!